# node js чтение уже существующего потока

Tags: node.js, потоки-данных

Задача вроде бы тривиальная: нужно читать аудиопоток. Но я новичок в node js, а в мануалах вижу только создание потока и чтение файлов (причем в 10 вариациях), в итоге запутался и часы напролет уже не могу разобраться: как быть если поток уже есть и его надо просто прочитать?

Например такой аудиопоток: http://air.radiorecord.ru:8102/chil_320

Что использовать fs или stream?

Comment: Использовать `http`, раз уж вы по HTTP получаете поток. https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverresponse это уже готовый стрим

Comment: @AlexeyTen да, то что нужно, спасибо!